# Block-scoped variable 'wizard' used before its declaration.ts(2448)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, visual-studio

Here is the code:

```
let args = {
      "wz_nav_style": "dots", // dots, tabs, progress
      "buttons": true,
      "navigation": 'all' // buttons, nav, all
    };

const wizard = new wizard(args);

wizard.init();

document.addEventListener("submitWizard", function (e) {
  alert("Form Submit");
});
```

I get the error:

> Block-scoped variable 'wizard' used before its declaration.ts(2448)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The constant name `wizard` overshadows the reference of the constructor named as the same. Changing the constant name to something other than the constructor would solve the problem.

```
const wiz = new wizard(args);

wiz.init();
```

Comment: Thank you @Charlie , but I get issue as cannot find the name wizard when using your reference

Comment: For you to use `new wizad()`, there should be a function or class by that name in your code. Or else, there should be a library which exports that name.